# Error: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const' but method is not marked const

Tags: c++, function, constants, operator-keyword

I have been running into some issues trying to compile a project.  It keeps giving me the message: "candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const' but method is not marked const".  Below are the functions that this error is appearing by.

```
bool operator<(const node& x) const{
    if(name < x.name){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool operator==(const node& x){
    if(name == x.name){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If anyone has any thoughts or knows where I've gone wrong with using const I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Welcome. It's good to post Complete Minimal Examples when you are asking debugging help! Even the error you posted is not complete.. :/ I will attempt to reply, but please take my advice for next time! =)

Comment: your `operator==` should be also marked as const. Make it your default to declare methods as const and only non-const them if needed. Fixing const correctness afterwards can be painful

Comment: Are you aware that `return name < x.name;` does the same as your pesky `if` but shorter and more readable? One should use `if( something ) return true; else return false;` if they paid by lines of code.

Comment: Half your "code" is explanation what the closing brace belongs too. If you need that much documentation on closing braces, it's **really** time to pick another style for your braces.

Comment: _"It keeps giving me the message"_ (A) Where? Post the full message, including the line and column number that it gives you. (A2) You missed out the places where you called these methods, which makes the question incomplete. (B) And you disagree with that message why? It seems quite clear to me. Bonus (C) Please do not write end-of-block comments in such trivial cases, where it is obvious what they're ending, and they are only visual noise, not any help.

Comment: @Slava `bool paidByLinesOfCode = something;` `bool result;` `if(paidByLinesOfCode)` `{` `result = true;` `}` `else` `{` `result = false;` `}` `return result;`. Questionable bonus points: only one `return`!

Comment: @Caleth you can also add another `if` - `if( result )  { return true; } else { return false; }` as well to make it even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
bool operator==(const node& x) {
```

to this:

```
bool operator==(const node& x) const {
```

in order to mark your other function const as well.

Comment: such an unintuitive syntax, should have been designed "const bool operator==" to maintain similarity with const param grammar.

Comment: Yeah @arviman, it can get confusing I am afraid..